# Creation POST API END point to save the data into two different APIs

Tags: javascript

May I know how to create a post API based on the following criteria

```
req.params.type ==gift then data need to saved into localhost:3000/api/gift and if 
req.params.type==voucher then data to be saved into localhost:3000/api/voucher
```

Comment: Hi Somulu, can you please provide more context and details to your question? Your environment? and also more details on what you really want so others can help?

Comment: #Mustafa Ehsan,   i have a node api as follow                                                                  
app.post('/api/redem', (req, res) => {
routes.postFunc(req, res);
});
 based on the params type(gift or voucher) either it have save the data into localhost:3000/api/gift or it has to save the data into localhost:3000/api/voucher.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's much better if you share your non-working code as a minimal reproducible example so that the proposed solution actually applies to your problem and can help future visitors with the same problem. Otherwise, there's a high likelihood that people will be tossing out random solutions that might not help you (or anyone else) much. See How to Ask and take the tour for more information on how to ask an on-topic question